# Can I use "has" in a question?

Tags: word-order, questions

**strong text**What the correct sentence?

1- "Does the equation has a solution?".

2- "Does the equation have a solution?".

3- "The equation has a solution?".

4- "The equation have a solution?".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Does it have it?" or  "it has it?". The first one is correct. The second one can be correct, but it is often used to expresses a degree of surprise, or as in a rhetorical question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tell us, has your question received an answer yet?

Has your equation a solution?

Can you use *has* in a question?

Yes. (#3 is good as a question.)

Comment: 2 and 3 are correct English, 1 and 4 are not.

Comment: @KateBunting #2 does not use "has" so I didn't include it as a viable answer.

Comment: "Does it has it?" is always incorrect in any register. In fact, the best answer is #2. (I'd replace the word "solution" with "answer". If you want to use "solution", then the first part should be "problem").

Comment: I'm not sure if my parenthetical comment was useful, so let me clarify. In general, questions have answers and problems have solutions.

Comment: @mhp Equations are solved. I believe the OP involved the use of "has."

Comment: Opps! Of course. For some reason I read it as question rather than equation. But my poor eye sight aside, It is "does he have it?" When you use "does", you cannot use "has".